# Voltage Reg ID Assistance

Tags: identification

Looking for the part identification for this voltage regulator on the Zotac GTX 1080 Mini. Hoping that you all will have more luck reading the text on the chip than I do. Trying to read it so I can figure out what surrounding components are missing with a schematic of the regulator. From what I can tell I see the following: **Line 1:** [Illegible] 3J, **Line 2:** 638. I already looked up what I could read on google and got negligible results so I must be missing something. Additionally I have researched the PCB and made several calls to the manufacturer, all futile.
Appreciate your help. Thank you.[image: Voltage Reg Circled in Red]

Comment: Just curious why do you want to know?

Comment: @Parker It's the only lead that I have on replacing some damaged surface mount components on the PCB. Since the board manufacturers often modify and adapt existing samples, I'm hoping to find a schematic for the chip. This can help me possibly reverse engineer the surrounding circuit if I'm lucky.

Comment: Looks like a multiphase Buck controller , perhaps for the Memory as it is on the end  something like this http://www.upi-semi.com/en-article-upi-362-2232